# Common sessions for node and php

Tags: php, node.js, session, nginx, redis

I want to create a social network using php on the server side with a chat for the users, and socket.io for node.js seems to be the answer. I've looked at other options like Ratchet already, and they have poor documentation, and are slower than node.js.  How do I make sure the node and php share a common session? Using mysql for sessions currently, but will do redis if necessary. And yes, nginx, since Apache is slowww.
How do I get node.js socket.io to share the $_SESSION['id'] I've created using php mysql?

Comment: User is logged and javascript make request to website for chat_token, and send to node.js for authentication. Node.js server verify chat_token with database and start accepting request with that token. If you want I can make it detailed. If it's what you need

Comment: javascript not really reliable, just need to store sessions in redis, and then pull it using node-redis